# Wordpress - Count users by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom field for my wordpress users: GENDER containing MALE and FEMALE.

Now I want to count the number of male and female users.

Best would be using functions.php

This code counts the total users. Can it be extended to count the genders?

```
add_shortcode( 'ucount', 'wpsites_user_count' ); //Count users
function wpsites_user_count() {
    $count = count_users();
    echo "There are " , $count['total_users'] , " on your website!";}
```

Comment: Check if you got your custom field in: `var_dump(get_users())` if so, add args for filter or `foreach` and manual count gender.

Comment: Sorry, I am no coder by profession. I need a bit more explanation.

Comment: Meanwhile I found the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This does the job:

```
add_shortcode( 'countfemale', 'wpsites_user_countfemale' ); //Count users
function wpsites_user_countfemale() {

$args  = array(
    'meta_key' => 'gender', //any custom field name
    'meta_value' => 'female' //the value to compare against
);

$users= new WP_User_Query( $args );

echo $users->get_total();

}
```